# Problemas com CSS numa pagina XHTML

Tags: css, eclipse

Ao iniciar o meu projeto criei toda a estrutura favorável para o bom funcionamento do arquivo CSS.

Está é minha pagina;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />
</h:head>


<h:body>

    <div id="tudo">

        <div id="topo">
            <div id="fone">TELEFONE DE CONTATO 011-3847-9076</div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
        Agendadorhbjhbscjbdhcjhbsd

        </div>
        <div id="conteudo"></div>
        <div id="rodape"></div>

    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Sendo que esse trecho do código não funcionou;

```
    <div id="menu">
    Agendadorhbjhbscjbdhcjhbsd

    </div>
```

A principio achei que fosse o eclipse que estivesse lento ao replicar a alteração, então eu dei um clear no projeto, dei um stop e start no TomCat e apertei F5 em teclado para atualiza a pagina web, porém não tive sucesso e ainda gerou uma mensagem de erro no consoles do eclipse;

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: 
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:283)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:125)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:99)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:127)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:173)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    ... 31 more
```

Obviamente eu sei que a causa é por conta de "Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host"

belaza, sem problema, o único problema é saber como resolver, pois nunca tive um problema como esse.

Aceito sugestões.

======================================================================

Veja como está a tag

```
#menu{
    position:relative;
    height:90px;
    font-size: 32px;

    background: black;
    filter:alpha(opacity=27);
    -moz-opacity:.27;
    opacity:.27;
}
```

O problema está aqui;

```
background: black;
filter:alpha(opacity=27);
-moz-opacity:.27;
opacity:.27;
```

Quando adiciono essas linhas de código no CSS ele faz com que não apareça as coisas escritas.

Porque isso acontece?
Como faço para corrigir isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente assim. O fato de não aparecer é que o texto do menu estava da mesma coisa do fundo, quando mudei para vermelho ele apareceu. Não sei como fica com o restante do seu estilo, mas executando aqui apareceu.

Isso não fara desaparecer o erro do servidor, mas **reforço a necessidade de colocar a tag h:html**.

```css
#menu{

    position:relative;
    height:90px;
    font-size: 32px;
    color:red;
    background: black;
    filter:alpha(opacity=27);
    -moz-opacity:.27;
    opacity:.27;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

   
<head>


<body>

    <div id="tudo">

        <div id="topo">
            <div id="fone">TELEFONE DE CONTATO 011-3847-9076</div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
        Agendadorhbjhbscjbdhcjhbsd

        </div>
        <div id="conteudo"></div>
        <div id="rodape"></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem, dê uma olhada.

Comment: Para eu entender, quando você chama essa página ela apresenta alguns textos exceto o quer esta na div menu e no servidor cospe aquela exceção, certo ?

Comment: pelo que eu entendi de sua pergunta, sim.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: muito bom, obrigado